# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio' on Mac (with Anaconda installed)

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, pyaudio

I'm trying to make a voice assistant with python following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjPuAKR_h4M) tutorial.
I installed Anaconda (individual version) on my Mac like the guy suggested. I said 'conda install PyAudio' in the Pycharm terminal and it successfully got installed (I presume):

> (venv) (base) Adityas-MacBook-Air:VoiceRec adityabakshi$ conda install
> pyaudio Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: done
>
> ### Package Plan
>
> environment location: /Users/adityabakshi/opt/anaconda3
>
> added / updated specs:
> - pyaudio
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> portaudio-19.6.0           |       h647c56a_4          75 KB
> pyaudio-0.2.11             |   py38h1de35cc_2         203 KB
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>                                        Total:         277 KB
> ```
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> portaudio          pkgs/main/osx-64::portaudio-19.6.0-h647c56a_4
> pyaudio            pkgs/main/osx-64::pyaudio-0.2.11-py38h1de35cc_2
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Downloading and Extracting Packages portaudio-19.6.0     | 75 KB     |
> ################################################################################## | 100%  pyaudio-0.2.11       | 203 KB    |
> ################################################################################## | 100%  Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done
> Executing transaction: done

However, when I ran my code:

```
import pyttsx3 as p
import speech_recognition as sr

engine = p.init()

engine.say("Hello, I'm your voice assistant")
engine.runAndWait()

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.energy_threshold = 10000
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, 1.2)
    print("listening..")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(text)
```

I got this error:

> /Users/adityabakshi/PycharmProjects/VoiceRec/venv/bin/python
> /Users/adityabakshi/PycharmProjects/VoiceRec/voiceapp.py Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/adityabakshi/PycharmProjects/VoiceRec/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py",
> line 108, in get_pyaudio
> import pyaudio ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/adityabakshi/PycharmProjects/VoiceRec/voiceapp.py", line 11,
> in 
> with sr.Microphone() as source:   File "/Users/adityabakshi/PycharmProjects/VoiceRec/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py",
> line 79, in **init**
> self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()   File "/Users/adityabakshi/PycharmProjects/VoiceRec/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py",
> line 110, in get_pyaudio
> raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation") AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I don't understand...I already installed anaconda and the pyaudio but how is this error showing? (I'm a beginner at Python). Can someone pls help me in fixing this? Thanks.